# Change properties of winform controls when using async. threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I'm creating a small utility program for my own use which opens links in the browser when reading from a file. I have a button the opens all links in a file like so:

```
    private void buttonOpenAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (LinksInFile.Count() != 0)
        {
            buttonOpenAllCancel.Visible = true;
            buttonOpenAll.Visible = false;
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(OpenAllURL), cts.Token);

        }
    }
```

Which is turn calls this:

```
    public static void OpenAllURL(Object obj)
    {
        CancellationToken token = (CancellationToken) obj;
        foreach (var link in LinksInFile) 
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                break;
            }
            OpenUrlInChrome(link, false);
            Thread.Sleep(7500); //to ensure the browser doesn't break
        }
    }
```

As you can see I have two buttons on my winform I'm switching the visiblity state of when I start executing, the visible button when executing this task should be the cancel button, which looks like this:

```
    private void buttonOpenAllCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cts.Cancel();
        cts.Dispose();
        buttonOpenAll.Visible = true;
        buttonOpenAllCancel.Visible = false;
    }
```

This code works as intended until someone decides to *not cancel* the opening of URL's, then the cancel button is still visible and you have to press it in order to enable the "open all" button again. I can't set the visibility of the buttons inside of the OpenAllURL method, because it is run in a separate thread from the UI. What are my options if I want to enable the "open all" button after the queued action is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to raise an event to tell the GUI to enable/disable the button from the other thread. How to do so is outlined well here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to implement this solution with my current setup, care to elaborate?

Comment: In your OpenAllURL method you can invoke an event which you have set up a listener for in your GUI enable/disable the button.